# Rotated textblock doesn't have the correct length

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, grid, textblock

I am trying to fill a Grid in a WPF application dynamically.

I'm creating a row and then some columns. in each column I am adding a textblock, like this:

```
GrdMainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(Height = new GridLength(150, GridUnitType.Pixel);
GrdMainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
{
  GrdMainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition {With = new GridLength(25, GridUnitType.Pixel)});
}
var header = new TextBlock {Text = "Header1", RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(-90), Width = 150, Margin = new Thickness(0), VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left};
.
.
.
Grid.SetColumn(header, 0);
Grid.SetRow(header, 0);
.
.
.
GrdMainGrid.Children.Add(header);
```

The textblock is rotated -90 degree.
While the size of the column is set to 25 pixel i doesn't show all text, when I increase the size of the column the text in textblock is also increased. see pic
[image]

[image]

I could understand this if the textblock wasn't rotated and it didn't fit in the column. But what has it to do with the size of the column when it's rotated.
And is it possible somehow to decrease the width of the column without decreasing size of text ?
Tnx in advance.

Comment: If got truncated then rotated.  Have you considered just stacking the text?

Comment: Almost a good question... Why on earth did you retype this (Difinition) instead of copy-pasting?

Comment: Blam, I am not sure I understand what you mean...

@HenkHolterman, Because I wanted to simplify it. There is much more in my code, which I didn't want to show here. just the relevant.

Comment: In the future, create a temp project and post working code. Makes the Q+A so much more valuable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, tnx I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a LayoutTransform instead of a RenderTransform.

```
    var header = new TextBlock { Text = "Header1", LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(-90), Width = 150, Margin = new Thickness(0), VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left };
```